# Animation of auto-hide docked windows in Visual Studio 2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, animation, ide, backwards-compatibility

Some people complain about animation of hiding panels (docked windows) in Visual Studio IDE, but I love it. And where had it gone in Visual Studio 2010?.. There are no option "Tools->Environment->General->Animate environment tools" any more. And all the "Visual experience options are enabled.

Is there a way to enable animation? Or did they just throw it away like dynamic help?.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed due to issues with WPF hosting Interop content, such as WinForms controls. It is fairly easy to show/hide Interop content in WPF tool window popups, but harder to animate it.

I believe this is also the reason the standard MDI mode was removed.

Comment: Sad... it's really easy to feel WPF was enforced in VS

Comment: +1 judging from problems I experienced myself this seems like a very plausible explanation.